# How do you route within a route in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm new to react and trying to get this whole routing thing down. I have page which I want to render multiple routes withing.

My main index.js file looks like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/adminDash" exact component={AdminDashMain}/>
                <Route path="/admin/ClientSearch" exact component={ClientDetailsMain}/>
                <Route path="/" exact component={LogIn}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>

    , document.getElementById('root'));
```

in client search main I have 3 components

```
class ClientDetailMain extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Header />
                <SubHeader username={this.props.match.params.username} />
                <Display username={this.props.match.params.username}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(ClientDetailMain);
```

I'm using `<Display/>` as a container and inside of that I want to have other route so that a person can go to

```
/admin/ClientSearch/refined
/admin/ClientSearch/general
/admin/ClientSearch/fixed
```

I figured out that the `/admin/ClientSearch` will match regardless so the header and subheader show on all 3 routes, however my routes which are written as:

```
const Display = () =>{
    return(
        <div>
           <Route path ='/admin/ClientSearch/refined' component={<Refined/>
           <Route path ='/admin/ClientSearch/general' component={<General/>
           <Route path ='/admin/ClientSearch/fixed' component={<Fixed/>
        </div>
    )
};

export default withRouter(ClientDisplay);
```

aren't displaying anything. Is this how I should be writing it? When I link to and of those 3 the header and subheader show up but the components in the individuals routes don't.

For example
`'/admin/ClientSearch/fixed'` shows the header and subheader but none of its own components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They key is in the "exact" attribute of your Routes. In addition, when you create a component that has routes inside, you can get the url of the previous routes through it's props. Like this example:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  render(){

    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
        <Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact} />
        <Route path='/admin' component={AdminArea} />
      </Switch>
    )
  }
}
```

Then you have your sub-routes like this:

```
const AdminArea = ({match}) => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path={`${match.url}/specie`} component={Component} />
    <Route exact path={`${match.url}/color`} component={Component} />
    <Route exact path={`${match.url}/user/:id`} component={Component}/>
  </Switch>
)
```